# Getting shape to show up on a form during runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a button and when clicked, i would like for a TMachine (aka TShape) to show up on the form.  Currenty i get no errors, but it never shows up on the form.

Code for button click

```
procedure TfDeptLayout.bAddMachineClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  machine: TMachine;
  shapeAsset,
  shapeShape,
  shapeNumber,
  shapeName: string;
begin
  if not OkToAdd() then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Please fill out form correctly!');
    Exit;
  end;

  ShapeAsset := Edit2.text;
  ShapeShape := Combobox1.Text;
  ShapeNumber := Edit3.Text;
  ShapeName := Edit1.Text;

  if sub = false then
    begin
      machine := TMachine.Create(self);
      machine.Parent := Self;
      machine.PlaceShape(0, FDB.GetWW(ShapeShape), FDB.GethW(ShapeShape), 
        '20', '20', ShapeName, ShapeNumber, ShapeAsset)
      //show save button
      //lockout add machine button
      //let user place machine top / left.
      //save all locations
      //save top and left for each tmachine to database
      //lockout save button
      //show add machine button
    end;

  if sub then
    ShowMessage('auto save form');

  ShowMessage('congrats you added a machine');        
end;
```

if needed i can show the TMachine unit?..

```
type    
  TMachine = class(TShape)
  private
    FOnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
  protected
    procedure DoMouseEnter; virtual;
  published
    property OnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent Read FOnMouseEnter write FOnMouseEnter;
  public
    mnName: string;
    mnAsset: string;
    mnNumber: string;
    mnIsPanel: string;
    mnBasicName: string;
    mnLShape: string;
    procedure PlaceShape(AM, sizeW, sizeH: Integer; ptop, pleft, name, order, 
      asset: string);
  end;

implementation

uses
  deptlayout;

procedure TMachine.CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  DoMouseEnter;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMachine.DoMouseEnter;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseEnter) then
    FOnMouseEnter(Self);
end;

procedure TMachine.PlaceShape(AM, sizeW, sizeH: Integer; ptop, pleft, name, 
  order, asset: string);
var
  myLabel: TLabel;
begin
  if ptop = '0' then
    Top := 136
  else
    Top := StrToInt(ptop);

  Width := sizeW;
  Height := sizeH;

  if pleft = '0' then
    Left := MyDataModule.fDB.LastX + 2  //set left
  else
    Left := StrToInt(pleft);

  MyDataModule.fDB.lastx := Left + sizeW;

  if AM = 1 then  //if in edit mode..
  begin
    //create label put inside the shape.
    myLabel := TLabel.Create(FDeptLayout);
    mylabel.Parent := FDeptLayout;
    mylabel.Left := Left;
    mylabel.Top := Top + 8;
    mylabel.Caption := '#' + mnNumber;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: What debugger says after the creation of the object ? Check the `Parent` property and position of the object (if it's not outside of the form client bounds).

Comment: @TLama: It's much more obvious than that!

Comment: What is `fdeptlayout`?

Comment: @Andreas, I should have step over the code... Good catch!

Comment: top and left are := 0  height and width are 65 (Tmachine)

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the creation of the machine and investigate its `Parent`, `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, `Height`, and `Visible` properties. Also, make sure it is actually created! (Is `sub` false?)

Comment: I dont see them,  all i have is FanchorRules(0,0) FAnchorOrgin (32,32) FOriginalParentSize (0,0) FExplicitLeft 0 , FExplicitTop 0, FExplicitHeight 65, FExplicitWidth 65,   unless thats what your talking about?

Comment: If `fDeptLayout` is the form this code is use `Self` instead of `fDeptLayout`. That way you can have multiple instances of it - in fact you may be trying to set the parent to a non-existent window.

Comment: How is fDeptLayout created? Do you have either Application.CreateForm(TfDeptLayout, fDeptLayout) in the dpr file, or a call like fDeptLayout := TfDeptLayout.Create(Application) somewhere in the calling code? Note: it is generally best to only use Application.CreateFrom for you application's mainform - see http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/createform

Comment: its a form i added,  Type TFDeptLayout = class(Tform)  .... var FDeptLayout : TFDeptLayout;    (Application.CreateForm(TfDeptLayout, fDeptLayout) )

Comment: Then FDeptLayout is a local variable, and will not be the SAME FDeptLayout GLOBAL variable referred to in the bAddMachineClick code above. Chnage this to Self, and it MAY work OK.

Comment: Updated post and added Self to it, still does not show up. It is creating it though. just not showing it ...where ever it is..

Comment: Voting to close. too localized / not constructive. OP should debug his own code carefully before posting it to SO.

Comment: Would i have to refresh the form for this to show up?

Comment: @Glen: No, that should not be necessary.

Comment: I create other TMachines(shapes) using other forms and place them on this form and they work. just when not createing the TMachine on this form and placeing it on this form.. very confusing..sorry its too localized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknown why this solved it, but after trying to find the parent for Machine by putting

```
showmessage('Machine Parent: '+Machine.parent.name);
```

it was giving access errors.

Deleted

```
Machine.parent := self;
```

Compile, build.  Then reaadded

```
Machine.parent := self;
```

and everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it doesn't work!

The code that adds the machine is inside `if not OkToAdd() then`, so it will only run if `not OkToAdd`. BUT! Even if this is the case, you `Exit` before you run the code! Hence, the code will never run!

Probably you mean it to be like this:

```
if not OkToAdd then
begin
  ShowMessage('Please fill out form correctly!');
  Exit;
end; //END!!!!!!
```

Comment: yes, dum mistake :D   but even after adding that it wont load.

Answer (score 3):

To summarise my comments above:

Change the refer to fDeptLayout to Self, as you have done in your edit:

```
procedure TfDeptLayout.bAddMachineClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  machine : TMachine;
  shapeAsset,
  shapeShape,
  shapeNumber,
  shapeName : string;
begin
if not OkToAdd() then
begin
  showmessage('Please fill out form correctly!');
  Exit;
End;

  shapeAsset := edit2.text;
  ShapeShape := Combobox1.Text;
  ShapeNumber := Edit3.Text;
  ShapeName := Edit1.Text;

  if sub = false then
    begin
      machine := TMachine.Create(self);
      machine.Parent := Self;
      machine.PlaceShape(0,FDB.GetWW(ShapeShape),FDB.GethW(ShapeShape),'20','20',ShapeName,ShapeNumber,ShapeAsset)
      //show save button
      //lockout add machine button
      //let user place machine top / left.
      //save all locations
      //save top and left for each tmachine to database
      //lockout save button
      //show add machine button
    end;

  if sub then
      showmessage('auto save form');

showmessage('congrats you added a machine');


end;
```

To avoid confusion in future, delete the global form variables that the Delphi IDE creates for all but the main form, and any other autocreated forms  - they are rarely if ever needed, and "pollute the namespace"